# How to always prefetch_related for a specific django model

Tags: django, django-models, prefetch

One of my models has number of related objects in it's `__str__`. This makes the admin site run very slow.

Is it possible to set up the model in a way that would always do prefetch_related, even if not explicitly requested?

Comment: Just add this to the `.objects` manager (or `._base_manager`).

Answer (score 5):

You can implement a [*manager* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/) that will automatically add a `.prefetch_related(..)` to the queryset.

For example:

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().prefetch_related('related_model')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …

    _base_manager = MyModelManager()
    objects = MyModelManager()
```

Comment: Hi Willem, thanks for this answer, however, there at times when you do this with a foreign key and you keep getting the warning of N+1 . I use this [package](https://pypi.org/project/nplusone/)  to track the N+1 issue, how best can one solve this ?

Answer (score 4):

Adding as an answer since I cannot add a comment ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59757404/10960328)):
The `_base_manager` attribute needs to be a class and not an object.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):   
    # …

    _base_manager = MyModelManager
    objects = MyModelManager()
```